# Nginx RTMP broadcasting multiple IP cameras

Tags: nginx, camera, streaming, rtmp

I've several IP cameras with Rtsp protocol with H264 encoded, I want to Nginx-RTMP publish the streamings to web, anyone has some ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) with the following command :

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtsp://<camera url> -c copy -f flv rtmp://<nginx host>/app/stream
```

You could also use [MonaServer](http://www.monaserver.ovh/) which doesn't need to be configured (if you just want to publish/play) and allows you to publish streams using RTMFP.